# How to do check in ApplicationDataServices?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am making a simple lightswitch app. I have a Report entity which contains info submitted by user. In this entity, user selects the level of seriousness from another table (there are 3 levels - minor, medium and critical.

Now, I need the lightswitch to send an email whenever someone submits a report with the critical level. I know that I need to send the email from the server side so I put my sendEmail method to the Inserted method. It is located in ApplicationDataService.lsml.cs and looks as follows:

```
  partial void Report_Inserted(IssueList entity)
    {           
            MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("myemail", "targetEmail");

            mm.Subject = "Subject";
            mm.Body = "Body";
            mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();

            NetworkCred.UserName = "myUserName";
            NetworkCred.Password = "Password";
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
            smtp.Port = 25;
            smtp.Send(mm);
       // }
    }
```

The email method is working, the problem is that I don't know how to check if the report level is critical. It should look like something like

```
if(level == LevelsSet.Where(e => e.Level == "Critical").FirstOrDefault()){
sendEmailMethod
}
```

But it is not working. Lightswitch does not seem to allow me to access the level data from here. Do you have any idea how to bypass this or where to move my sendEmail method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd personally add the email handler to the Report_saving() handler.

```
public partial class ApplicationDataService
{
    partial void SaveChanges_Executing()
    {
        var changes = this.DataWorkspace.ApplicationData.Details.GetChanges();
        var inserted = changes.AddedEntities;
        foreach (var entity in inserted)
        {
            try
            {
                var report = (Report)entity;
                if (report.Level.LevelName == "Critical")
                {
                    sendNotification(report);
                }
            }
            catch (InvalidCastException) {} 
           // Do nothing - this is just a simple way to filter the entity types 
           // in the EntityChangeSet 
        }

    }

    void sendNotification(Report report) {  
        MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("myemail", "targetEmail");

        mm.Subject = "Critical Report submitted!";
        mm.Body = report.ToString();
        mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();

        NetworkCred.UserName = "myUserName";
        NetworkCred.Password = "Password";
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
        smtp.Port = 25;
        smtp.Send(mm);

    }
}
```

This will quickly scan any new Report entities on commit.  You don't necessarily want to fire this message as people finish inserting, as they might have accidentally selected the wrong Level. The event will be fired if the added report entity's corresponding LevelName field is "Critical".

HTH